# Failure when installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Message: The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI2 (0,0,0), partition #2 (sda) at /boot/efi failed. What is causing this failure?

Comment: Did you partition the disk yourself?

Comment: I just got it to install.  I deleted the EFI and set it up again in the installer and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When trying to dual-boot Windows 10 and Linux, received this error as the 500mb Window's recovery file had a boot flag, so the installation tried to put the efi/boot here. To fix it, opened gparted, and took the boot flag off this file. Now Windows boot manager and ubuntu boot are on the same efi file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Boot into a live USB Linux session, such as the "Try Ubuntu" option that comes with the Linux installation package or Boot-Repair-Disk live USB.
2. Open a utility such as Gparted, KDE Partition Manager, or other partition manager.  I used Gparted.
3. Identify the EFI boot partition.  On my computer this partition was named dev/sda1, it was 100MB, and it was NTFS.  It was labeled "System Reserved" and flagged "boot,esp"
4. Use partition manager to reformat the efi boot partition to a Fat 16 or 32 system and set flags to "boot,esp".
5. Shut off computer.
6. Install Ubuntu no problem.